# Words for describing a video footage/picture showing excessive body exposure

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I know there are choices like obscene\profane\explicit etc, but most of them imply an attitude(with the exception of "explicit").
My questions are:

1. What would journalism\literature use here?
2. Are there any neutral\objective substitute for "explicit"?

Comment: They tend to just say "warning"

Comment: Thx for comment! Do they use "warning" right before "footage"? It seems a bit unspecific to me

Comment: *Obscene*, *profane*, and *explicit* are all formal English. *Obscene* has a legal meaning as well as various non-legal meanings; *profane* is generally used in a religious context; and *explicit* is more neutral and has many meanings not all of which relate to obscenity/nudity/blasphemy/etc. Which word is best depends on the PRECISE meaning you wish to convey - in terms of content, your attitude to the content (ban it? enjoy it? or something more neutral), and what you believe the effect is (will it deprave or corrupt, sexually excite, or what?). Which you don't tell us.

Comment: @StuartF Sound comment that might well make an answer?

Comment: There is no 'formal' one… and by 'formal…' you seem to have meant 'correct one.' If I'm mistaken, please show how…

Comment: @StuartF Thanks for solid comment and I'm sorry for confusing questions. I re-edited them to make more sense.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Sorry for the confusion. In a nutshell I'm looking for a neutral adjective that the media would use here (other than explicit)

Comment: "explicit" is the word that's often used in warnings at the beginning of movies/TV shows that contain content intended for mature audiences.

Comment: You use the term “excessive.” That in itself is a value judgment. Does Botticelli’s Birth of Venus use “excessive body exposure”?

Comment: @Xanne Agreed, I tried my best. Maybe there is no objectivity in adjectives after all.

Comment: @Barmar got it, imma just stick with explicit until something new shows up lol

Comment: Judgement sems to be inherent in specifying "excessive". so your question (what term for it doesn't imply an attitude) makes no sense

Comment: @Fuyun Look back at the many movies made when censors forced Hollywood's married couples to sleep in twin beds instead of doubles, or to keep at least one foot on the floor, or both.

Like it or loathe it, 'excessive' is by definition an individual choice, which is why no words or phrases will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

**gratuitous nudity**

I’d offer a link, but a google search for the term will be more informative and entertaining.

And to reassure the moderators, I don’t think we’ll be running out of these links any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

A "picture" is one single image (such as a single photograph or a painting).

Films, movies and videos are the words used to describe motion pictures.

All of the following are natural-sounding English sentences:

- Some scenes within the film display ***nudity***. Viewer discretion is advised.
- There is ***nude*** footage present within the film.
- ***Nudity*** is depicted through-out the film.
- the painting was of a ***nude*** woman.